# Are there any good open-sourced comet web servers for ASP.NET MVC applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sockets, comet, server-push

I'm looking for one that can be used to handle many long poll clients and does not create a thread for each request.

Comment: How is it possible not to create another thread? Infact, why would it chose to even do that?

Comment: Tornado is able to serve requests with just one thread. Instead of spawning a new thread per HTTP request, Tornado has an infinite loop in its core. At the beginning of the loop, it uses system calls to sense whether or not there are clients that wants to connect to the server without actually reading any data. Immediately afterward, those requests are processed. Note that while the loop is processing those requests, new connections can still hit the server. They are just pending for acceptance. In the loop's next iteration, those pending requests will get processed again.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to IIS (ASP.NET) page works on its own thread. A good library should not create some extra threads. So, I'm using [PokeIn](http://pokein.com) inside my solution(online learning) and it doesnt create extra threads. It has a free community edition but not an open source :(

Answer (score 0):

you can check the source code for Pokein [here](http://pokein.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

**edit**
It seems that the latest source available isn't that up to date, my bad. Check out their [website](http://www.pokein.com/) instead.
I've been using it