# Is there a free open source that implements Comet or Push?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, comet, push

I am looking for a free implementation for Comet or Push. Here is an example of chat done by comet: http://www.phpchatsoftware.com/phpbb/
I have my own server.

Is there any thing like this?

P.S. I am using asp.NET, on server and jQuery on client.

Is there anything new? or maybe this is the last technological free open source achievement:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322196/are-there-any-good-open-sourced-comet-web-servers-for-asp-net-mvc-applications

Answer (score 2):

[WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/downloads) has a free community edition, but it's limited to just 10 concurrent users. There are also [PunHub](http://www.pubnub.com/tutorial/javascript-push-api) and open-source [erlycomet](http://code.google.com/p/erlycomet/). I am not aware of any open source comet servers in .Net though.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source ASP.NET comet implementation called [aspComet](https://github.com/nmosafi/aspcomet) on GitHub. The solution comes with a sample chat project.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322196/are-there-any-good-open-sourced-comet-web-servers-for-asp-net-mvc-applications), PokeIn is probably the best you will be able to do. It isn't open source, but there is a free community edition. Check it out: http://www.pokein.com/. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, But I asked Open Source and Free. I don't need restrictions.

Comment: If you need a stable solution, better to use PokeIn. Free community edition allows 20 concurrent connection. So, if you reach 20 concurrent users, you may buy a commercial one.

Comment: How does PokeIn works? does it open connection for each client?

Comment: @Naor: I know what you asked for, but that service doesn't exist yet. This, or maybe HeavyWave's suggestions, are the best you will be able to do.

Comment: @Naor: sure. it is the way how ajax thing works. better you ask it to the community for details at: http://www.pokein.com/Discussions.aspx

Comment: @Zuuum: No thanks, I don't want remain open connection with each connected client. This is not optimal and not efficient.

Comment: @Naor: So, Push or Comet is not for you. You need an open connection to let server push into it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/)? And here is a working example of SignalR called [JabbR](http://jabbr.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Push Framework, an open source server development library.
A Chat Client-Server application is among the demos.

Comment: I have reached to this site: http://www.pushframework.com. It is written with c++. How can I use that using c# and .Net?